# Elasticsearch ESRejectedExecutionException using _msearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my system, I currently have 2 nodes both running Ubuntu 14.04 and elasticsearch 1.5.2, one is a combined master and data node, and the other is a client node, with settings like:

**Master node:**

```
http.enabled: true  
node.data: true  
node.master: true  
cluster.name: mvtest
```

**Client node:**

```
http.enabled: true  
node.data: false  
node.master: false  
cluster.name: mvtest
```

All of the other settings are ES 1.5.2 defaults.  When I try to post to the _msearch endpoint, using a file like:

```
{}  
{“query”: {“multi_match”: {“operator”:”and”, “query”: “1”, “fields”: [“_id”]}}}  
{}  
{“query”: {“multi_match”: {“operator”:”and”, “query”: “2”, “fields”: [“_id”]}}}  
{}  
{“query”: {“multi_match”: {“operator”:”and”, “query”: “3”, “fields”: [“_id”]}}}  
…
{}  
{“query”: {“multi_match”: {“operator”:”and”, “query”: “999”, “fields”: [“_id”]}}}  
{}  
{“query”: {“multi_match”: {“operator”:”and”, “query”: “1000”, “fields”: [“_id”]}}}
```

I get MANY errors in the logs of the form:

```
[2015-05-20 18:57:22,150][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [master] [genedoc_mygene_allspecies_current_1][8], node[4ara0M7SReSEPKrZM2g5Gg], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@5104e7e5] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException: rejected execution (queue capacity 1500) on org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23@18e20fd8
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsAbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(EsAbortPolicy.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor.execute(EsThreadPoolExecutor.java:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.execute(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:551)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:176)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.start(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:158)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:52)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:100)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:43)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportMultiSearchAction.doExecute(TransportMultiSearchAction.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportMultiSearchAction.doExecute(TransportMultiSearchAction.java:39)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.execute(NodeClient.java:98)
at org.elasticsearch.client.FilterClient.execute(FilterClient.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler$HeadersAndContextCopyClient.execute(BaseRestHandler.java:92)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.multiSearch(AbstractClient.java:364)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestMultiSearchAction.handleRequest(RestMultiSearchAction.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:53)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.executeHandler(RestController.java:225)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:170)
        at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer.internalDispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:121)
        at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer$Dispatcher.dispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.NettyHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(NettyHttpServerTransport.java:329)
        at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.HttpRequestHandler.messageReceived(HttpRequestHandler.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:60)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:194)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Interestingly, when I use the _msearch endpoint on the master node, the query returns, but these errors fill the logs.  When I use the _msearch endpoint on the client node using the same query, it will often (but not always) trigger a timeout, and then fill the logs with these errors.

I assume it must have something to do with the thread pool queue, but after reading the ES documentation, I’m not sure how to fix this.  I have tried to unbound the search queue using type: cached, and also tried to change the search queue size, all to no avail. However, when I unbound the queue, the error changes to a TransportService not closed error.

I’m still very new to elasticsearch, so I’m hoping someone out there will have some ideas about what’s happening here.

Thanks so much, and let me know if I forgot any relevant background information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EsRejectedExecutionException in elasticsearch for parallel search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793530/esrejectedexecutionexception-in-elasticsearch-for-parallel-search)